# How do I configure a machine to respond or not respond to ping requests?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ping

How can I manage my Ubuntu machine so it doesn't (or does) respond to [PING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) (ICMP ECHO_REQUEST - type 8) requests?

Normally almost all computers in a LAN network respond to ping with an ICMP ECHO_REPLY, but how to turn it off?

How to manage it? How to manage other types of [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) requests?

Answer (score 4):

Another option (not using a firewall) is to set a Linux kernel option.

As most things are accessed as files in Linux, kernel settings are mapped into the special `/proc` file system

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

you can also make this permanent by setting the value in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

then execute sysctl with `-p` flag to activate

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 3):

You can this through two methods: using `ufw` or `iptables`.

## Using [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

You need to add:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

to:

```
/etc/ufw/before.rules
```

then run:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

## Using [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Add the following rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -o eth0 -j ACCEPT          
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT     
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT       
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: `How do I configure a machine to respond or not respond to ping requests?` Which one did you explain?